# Disable WebView touch events in Android

Tags: android, webview, touch

How do you disable all touch events in an Android WebView (or scrolling in particular)? I would like the activity to handle all touch events.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

```
mWebView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return true;
    }
});
```

Disables all touch events on a `WebView` because the touch listener is executed before the default touch behavior of the `WebView`. By returning `true` the event is consumed and isn't propagated to the `WebView`.

Using `android:clickable="false"` does not disable touch events.

Comment: Then, how to restore the events? Imagine I have to temporarily disable them and then re-enable them when I need.

Comment: Actually, setting both `android:clickable` and longClickable should do the trick for a webview

Comment: Hosane, just change OnTouchListener return false, it will do the trick

Answer (score 1):

If I got you right you just have to overwrite the [onTouchEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#onTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29) method.

Comment: Most likely that should work. I was wondering if there was a property or something more straightforward than that.

Comment: Ah I see well then you might want to try to give your WebView this layout parameter android:clickable="false". I'm not sure if it works but theoretically it should as WebView is inherited from View.

Comment: @hpique  can you post the solution again. The current ones in the post are not working