# How to disable Clicking of WebView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-webview

I have Linear Layout which contains Only WebView. What i want to do is to disable the click in Webview, means I want the event to be called associated with RelativeLayout bg_stepsContainer. I've used the android:clickable="false" Here is code

```
 <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:minHeight="30dp" 
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:id="@+id/bg_stepsContainer"
                    >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/stepslcontainer"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false" >

                    <WebView
                        android:id="@+id/bg_stepsToReproduce"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:clickable="false"
                        android:focusable="false"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="false" 

                        android:textColor="@color/solid_black" />

                    </LinearLayout>
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/stepsArrow"
                        android:layout_width="10dp"
                        android:layout_height="10dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                       android:clickable="false"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_right_arrow" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Any Suggestions are Appreciated!

Comment: maybe this helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415528/how-to-pass-the-onclick-event-to-its-parent-on-android

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853794/disable-webview-touch-events-in-android this will helpful

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
mWebView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
       return true;
    }  
});
```

Using android:clickable="false" does not disable touch events.

Comment: @GowthamanM just remove the `OnTouchListener` from the webview.

Comment: how you can remove the OnTouchListener from the webview ?