# How to Make WebView Clickable False and True

Tags: android, android-webview, webviewclient

I am Using Web view in my application every thing is working fine for me, but i am having small problem. When Url contains **Disclaimers** i should not allow web-view should be clickable. But in all other cases web-view should be clickable.

```
 @Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    if(url.contains("Disclaimers")){
                        view.setClickable(false);

                        //Here clickable should be fasle.

                        return true;
                    }else{
                        // In this clickable should be true.
                        view.setClickable(true);

                        if(!url.contains("/Home.mvc/Trade")){
                            showProgressLayout();
                        }
              if(url.contains("/Home.mvc/Trade")){
                            openTradeScreen(url);
                        }else{
                            view.loadUrl(url); 
                        }                 
                        return true;
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but someone else might also find [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3856199/6078214) useful. Seems to solve things better than setting just clickable to false.

For lazyness' sake I'll copy the solution from that answer here (edited for this scenario, assuming `view` is the webview) :)

```
view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return true;
    }
});
```

The original answer gives the following explanation too:

> Disables all touch events on a WebView because the touch listener is executed before the default touch behavior of the WebView. By returning true the event is consumed and isn't propagated to the WebView.
>
> Using android:clickable="false" does not disable touch events.

Comment: this does not allow scrolling.

Answer (score 2):

Try `view.setEnabled(false);` to stop user Interaction on **WebView**. As i am sure  `view.setClickable(true);` will not work for you properly.