# Disable the facility of WebView in android?

Tags: java, android, android-webview, swipe, epub

In order to display `Epub`, I used `WebView`.There for , by this [`WebView`] I can select the `Text` by `touching` and `holding` and some facility appears like copy , find , share etc. After that, I used `Swipe` to change the page by right or left , but after using `Swipe` I can't select the text by touching and holding , what is the solution ?

I didn't share the code because it is too long , but i can share it necessary .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mWebView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return true;
    }
});
```

Disables all touch events on a `WebView` because the touch listener is executed before the default touch behavior of the `WebView`. By returning `true` the `event` is consumed and isn't propagated to the `WebView`.

Using `android:clickable="false"` does not disable touch events.

URL : [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853794/disable-webview-touch-events-in-android)