# Place a webview under a Webview in a ScrollView

Tags: android, webview, scrollview

I have created two `webviews` and need to put them under each other but it overlaps each other instead of going under each other. Which means that only the second screen `webview` is being displayed and not both.

> #### activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />


    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

> #### MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    WebView webView, webview2;
    CheckBox cbk1, cbk2;

    @SuppressLint("JavascriptInterface")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview2);
            webview2 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);
            webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/nextscreen.html");
            webview2.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/newscreen2.html");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using `FrameLayout` which stacks views on top of other. Use `LinearLayout` instead.

Comment: How can I change it a `scrollview`? So i can go up and down the whole screen? Would I have to just change `LinerLayout` to `ScrollView`

Comment: You can place your `LinearLayout` inside `ScrollView` to make it scrollable.

Comment: I put the `LinerLayout` in a `ScrollView` but now it only shows the first `webview` and not both.

Answer (score 1):

Just put it in a `LinearLayout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  orientation="vertical">

  <WebView
  android:id="@+id/webview2"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="50dp"
  android:autoLink="web"
  android:scrollbars="none"
  android:textColor="@android:color/black" />


  <WebView
  android:id="@+id/webview1"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="570dp"
  android:autoLink="web"
  android:scrollbars="none"
  android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: How can I change it a `scrollview`? So i can go up and down the whole screen? Would I have to just change `LinerLayout` to `ScrollView`

Comment: You'll need to wrap the `LinearLayout` with a `ScrollView` element. But this way you will probably have collision with the `WebView` touches, unless you make the `WebView` not touchable...

Comment: What do you mean by none touchable? Do not understand.

Comment: Like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853794/disable-webview-touch-events-in-android. but first check if it works without it...

Answer (score 0):

because you are using `FrameLayout` as root . replace `FrameLayout`   to `LinearLayout`and add `android:orientation="vertical"`

Try this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical"
>

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:autoLink="web"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />


<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="570dp"
    android:autoLink="web"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

</LinearLayout >
```

Comment: How can I change it a `scrollview`? So i can go up and down the whole screen? Would I have to just change `LinerLayout` to `ScrollView`

Comment: @AnonymousZA you can add a `ScreollView` inside root `LinearLayout`

Comment: @AnonymousZA if my answer helped you pls accept it thanks